# Evitar que se vuelva a ingresar los mismo registros al momento de ejecutar un Bulk Insert?

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

tengo un error en este sp con el bulk insert, al comienzo ejecuta me actualiza los campos que envio por parametros en el sp, pero cuando ejecuto de nuevo el sp se vuelve a recargar los mismos datos en la tabla fija direcciones, lo cual no quiero que eso pase porque estoy sobrecargando esa tabla,
me podrian orientar como puedo solucionar este error

Comment: Puede ser mediante una llave primaria o una tabla intermedia. La instrucción BULK INSERT no puede llevar filtros. Siempre se carga todo el archivo.

Comment: muchas gracias, es que soy novato en el sql server pero con tu comentario resolvi ayer el error